# Should the identity of a binary operation be unique?

Tags: binary-operations

I was trying to work out the identity of a binary operation and I found that there were infinitely many possible identities for a certain value. My confusion is whether this is a valid identity or should there be a unique identity element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unique. If $e$ and $e'$ are two identities ($\therefore$ left and right identities), then:

- $e \star e' = e$ since $e'$ is a right identity.
- $e\star e' = e'$ since $e$ is a left identity.

So $e = e'$.

Comment: the exact question is : (a, b)*(c, d) = (ac, bc + d), on the set {(x, y) ∈R x R}      Now i get infintely many identity elements if i put a=0. So does an identity exist?

Comment: here's what i did - (a, b) * (e1, e2) = (a e1, b e1 + e2) = (a,b). Now if i put a=0, e1 can have any value..

Comment: An identity must work for every element, not just one. Consider over R: 2 * 0 = 0, but that doesn't mean 2 is an identity.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for clearing that up